# ADF header in csv file

Tags: azure-data-factory

I'm wondering if anyone can help with my problem. I'm trying to add headers to my csv file in ADF. I've had renamed the columns using 'select' but this still doesn't seem to work.

Data flow below:

I have a derive column function which concats firstname and lastname of student into one cell. (ignore the red expression error I had misspelt column name when taken screenshot)

[image: Derive Column]

Then below you can see I have included 'select' in the dataflow. This selects the concatenated column and naming this as 'Name'.

[image: Select Columns]

Therefore in the csv file I expect to see a header row at the top of the csv file but this doesn't happen. The csv file just contains the data from the database. Anyone know how to add this?

Update:
Dataset for sink
[image: Dataset for sink]

Comment: How is your Sink DataSet defined?

Comment: @JoelCochran have updated question with dataset

Comment: Check the box for "First row as header".

Comment: You also have no Column Delimiter selected, is that intentional? If this is standard CSV, you'll want the Delimiter to be , and the "Quote character" set to ".

Comment: I checked 'First row as header' and still doesn't include a header in the file. Also regarding the delimiter, I've set no delimiter as I am inserting ',' via the query when selecting from the database

Comment: It's possible that with no delimiter, it can't output a header row. Are you saying your query builds a string with the commas? What is the use case for that approach rather than letting Data Flow do its thing?

Comment: I have done this approach as some fields in the database includes ',' , therefore if I were to use a ',' as the delimiter the pipeline throws an error. Do you know of a work around to add header another way?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240212/discussion-between-joel-cochran-and-user406480).

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @Joel Cochran in the comments, if you select no delimiter in the dataset properties, it can’t output the header row in the sink file.

As a workaround, you can add a **header** row to your data rows in **source** transformation by using **union**.

1. In your `source` transformation, in source options, select **Input as Query**, and in Query option, write the query to add header row and **union** it to data rows as below.

   ```
   select 'Name' as Name
   union
   select concat(firstname,',',lastname) as Name from tb1
   ```

[image]

**Source data preview:**

[image]

2. In the `select` transformation, you can select the required column from the source.

[image]

3. Sink delimiter dataset:

[image]

4. In the `sink` transformation, connect the sink to sink **delimiter dataset** and in settings, you can provide the sink filename in Output to a single file by selecting **Output to a single file** in the **Filename option**.

[image]

**Sink data preview:**

[image]

5. As you don’t get the header row in the sink file when you select no delimiter in the sink dataset. The output file starts with data rows when you run the pipeline.

[image]